# "The launch of my career" can we choose the word launch?

Tags: word-choice

Or only the word beggining ? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, you certainly can use "the launch of my career." You should know, though, that there is a subtle difference in meaning or nuance when you choose *launch* instead of *beginning.* For me, launch implies that your career was set in motion with a lot of momentum from the very beginning, such as is true when one opens a business that is soon successful. My own career has been a slow meandering from lower level clerical jobs to quasi-technical upper administrative, etc., finally depositing me in a role as an instructor of adults learning English as an additional language, so I would never refer to the "launch" of my career. But I would use "beginning" for such a gradual ramp-up to what is now a solid career path.